# how to fix Nan javascript

Tags: javascript, nan, stimulusjs, isnan

when I start to write in the htPrice field, Nan appears in the ttcPrice field, how can i fix this?

```
calculatTTC() {
     const htPrice = parseFloat(this.htpriceTargets[0].value);
     const tvaPercent = parseFloat(this.tvaTargets[0].value);
     const ttcPrice= parseFloat(preTaxPrice + vatPercent);
    if (isNaN(htPrice) && isNaN(tvaPercent)) {
        this.ttcPriceTargets[0].value = 'the value is not correct';
    } else {
        this.ttcPriceTargets[0].value = ttcPrice;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `this.htpriceTargets[0].value` defined?

Comment: The `if` condition  should be an OR, not AND, but it is just easier to make the check on the result:  `if (isNaN(ttcPrice))`. Also, there's no need to call `parseFloat` on numbers. So skip that third call. You should also check your variable names. `vatPercent` and `tvaPercent`? And what is `preTaxPrice`?

Comment: yes I'm working with Stimulus js, ttcPriceTargets is a div in twig Symfony

Comment: Please, provide more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You should check that htPrice OR tvaPercent is NaN. And only if both are not - calculate TTC.

```
calculatTTC() {
    const htPrice = parseFloat(this.htpriceTargets[0].value);
    const tvaPercent = parseFloat(this.tvaTargets[0].value);
     
    if (isNaN(htPrice) || isNaN(tvaPercent)) {
        this.ttcPriceTargets[0].value = 'the value is not correct';
    } else {
        const ttcPrice= parseFloat(preTaxPrice + vatPercent);
        this.ttcPriceTargets[0].value = ttcPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: @learn If it works - mark this answer as solution, please :)

Comment: There is someone already slapped me a minus, for unknown reason, lol